# Get an object from a struct with an array inside

Tags: arrays, json, struct, rust

I have this json from an external:

```
  "description": {
    "type": "doc",
    "version": 1,
    "content": [
      {
        "type": "paragraph",
        "content": "data",
      }
    ]
  },
```

And I want to create and object with a struct

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Content {
  type: String,
  content: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Description {
  type: String,
  version: i32,
  content: [Content;1],
}
```

And now the object

```
let data = Description {
    type: "doc".into(),
    version: 1,
    content: Content [{
       type: "paragraph".into(),
       content: "data".into(),
   }]
}
```

Two problems:

1. The code gives me an error within the struct, with the word "type", I think it is because it's reserved in Rust.

```
type: String,
```

2. The other error is when I create the object in the content array.

```
Content [{
    type: "paragraph".into(),
    content: "data".into(),
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

For your first point: yes `type` is reserved in Rust. You can fix this by renaming the field through `serde`:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Content {
  #[serde(rename = "type")]
  content_type: String,
  content: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Description {
  #[serde(rename = "type")]
  descr_type: String,
  version: i32,
  content: [Content;1],
}
```

Alternatively you could escape it by replacing it with `r#type`, but renaming through `serde` is generally preferred over that.

For your second point, that's not how you make an array in Rust. You simply place the value(s) in the `[]`s, like so:

```rs
let data = Description {
    type: "doc".into(),
    version: 1,
    content: [
       Content {
          type: "paragraph".into(),
          content: "data".into(),
       }
   ]
}
```

You may also want to consider replacing that with a `Vec` depending on how strong your guarantees are regarding the incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the two problems:

1. Yes, `type` is a reserved keyword in Rust. For the `Content` struct, maybe use `content_type`, and for the `Description` struct, use `description_type`.
2. `type` is also the error here. You also didn't write the `content` field correctly. It should be:

```rs
let data = Description {
    desc_type: "doc".into(),
    version: 1,
    content: [
        Content {
            content_type: "paragraph".into(),
            content: "data".into(),
        }
    ],
};
```